# How to run two different queries based on IF condition?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario in which a table might exist in some databases. I need my query to run when the table exists and also when it doesn't. The below query when ran, gives an error **Operand should contain 1 column(s)**. How can I make this query work without using a stored procedure? I need to use it with PySpark SQL.

```
SELECT IF(
    EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbdemo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tier_report') > 0,
    (SELECT a.*, b.tierchangedate, b.tierchangetype 
        FROM 
            (SELECT mobile, enrolledstorecode as storecode, tier as customertier, isprofileupdated, DATE(profileupdatedate) as profileupdatedate, modifiedenrolledon as enrolledon, referralcode, (CASE WHEN(countrycode IS NULL) THEN '91' ELSE countrycode END) as countrycode 
            FROM dbdemo.member_report) a 
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT mobile, DATE(tierchangedate) as tierchangedate, tierchangetype FROM dbdemo.tier_report) b 
        ON a.mobile=b.mobile), 
    (SELECT mobile, enrolledstorecode as storecode, tier as customertier, isprofileupdated, DATE(profileupdatedate) as profileupdatedate, modifiedenrolledon as enrolledon, referralcode, (CASE WHEN(countrycode IS NULL) THEN '91' ELSE countrycode END) as countrycode 
            FROM dbdemo.member_report));
```

Comment: Can you format the query more readably, not all on one line?

Comment: You can't use a query that returns multiple rows and/or columns as an expression. You need to do this in a stored procedure, not a subquery.

Comment: @Barmar Is there any other way I can run this? I want to avoid using stored procedure. Thanks

Comment: So the intent is to not query the `tier_report` table if it doesn't exist? You can't do that in a single query. All the tables in the query have to exist, even if you don't use them.

Comment: Where are `a` and `b` in the second subquery? It's not joining with `tier_report`, but it still has `b.tierchangedate` and `b.tierchangetype` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: @Barmar Fixed the second subquery. It's now showing Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @Barmar What can I do other than stored procedure?

Comment: I think you're out of luck. SQL isn't a procedural or interpreted language, it can't be used dynamically like this.

Comment: You could run  `create table of not exists` first and then join into the empty table. An empty table won't take up much room.